# Database Design - Column In One Table References Two Tables

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

Here is an example of what I have (take Stack Overflow).  I have 2 tables, `Questions` and `Answers`.  I also have a `Comments` table.  The Comments table will reference both Questions and Answers.

How should I set up the database?  Have 2 columns in Comments, a QuestionId and AnswerId.  Have one table for both Questions and Answers?  Have a table in between that somehow tells me Question or Answer?

**EDIT:** Found the SO Data explorer, it uses one table for both Questions and Answers ... I just don't like the `POSTS` table having so many NULLS in it.  Does that have any negative effects, like on performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow models the questions and answers as being the same entity: `POSTS`.  They have identical properties, aside from indicating the answer where accepted/granted.

Comments get their own table, and relate to the respective post using a foreign key -- the `post_id`.

Without needing to load the monthly SO dumps, [you can view (and query) the SO schema via the StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

Comment: Finally got a chance to look at SO data.  The only thing I don't like is that there are a lot of NULL columns.  Does that affect performance in any way?

Comment: @Martin: That depends on the queries you need to run.

Answer (score 2):

Create another relation `Post_Type` to keep track of whether the ID in your `Comments` table is a question or an answer.

```
post_type varchar(20) NOT NULL,
post_type_id tinyint PRIMARY KEY,
```

Then in your `Comments` table, add `Post_Type.post_type_id` as the foreign key, in addition to the attribute that keeps track of your Question Id/Answer Id.

You won't need two columns (QuestionId + AnswerId) in the `Comments` table, because that will give you `null` in either columns, in your scenario problem domain.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you can have comments on both questions and answers? You will have 5 tables:

```
question
answer
comment
question_comment
answer_comment
```

The table `question_comment` will have a `comment_id` and a `question_id`. Similar deal with `answer_comment`.